# Running OpenCL programs on baremetal RISC-V core

Tags: opencl, riscv, pocl

I'm a newbie in OpenCL programs. I would appreciate it if you can guide me with my question.

For a project, I developed a multi-threaded RISC-V core in C that is synthesized using HLS. I want to run OpenCL program on this RISC-V core but I don't know what exactly I need to do. I checked POCl and it seems that it supports RISC-V devices. So compiling the OpenCL kernel using POCL for bare metal RISC-V would be enough to be able to run the OpenCL kernel on my RISC-V core?

Comment: I suspect you'll have a lot of problems trying to get this to actually work. Experienced people struggle to get OpenCL to work with AMD GPUs, so I doubt a RISC-V CPU is going to be easier. I wish you the best of luck, but would recommend trying to find someone who has actually successfully achieved what you're trying to achieve for advice, or do what you're trying to do a different way.